# react-bootstrap remove border from nav-dropdown

Tags: drop-down-menu, navbar, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to remove the border from a dropdown menu within my navbar. I'm using a React-Bootstrap Navbar with a NavDropdown component.

[nav dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBJyF.png)

```
 <Nav className="ms-auto">
            <NavDropdown title="shop">
                <NavDropdown.Item href="/tops">tops</NavDropdown.Item>
                <NavDropdown.Item href="/dresses">dresses</NavDropdown.Item>
                <NavDropdown.Item href="all">all</NavDropdown.Item>
            </NavDropdown>
```

```
#shop-menu {
  border: none;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
  display: none !important;
}
```

I've tried overriding the border with css and with bootstrap classes but can't get anything to work.